# Language switcher in joomla 3 not showing flags

Tags: joomla, module

I'm trying to make the language switcher to work, I have already made all menus for each language I was gonna use, but when I enable this module, It just shows me the name of the module(when I put it to show), not the flags. What should i do?

Comment: hi.. did you got solution for this then please help me i am stuck in same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I lost a full day of my life with this topic.

The issue was that **language tag** was badly setup in System -> Language Manager -> Content
For example for French I had **fr** when it should have been **fr-FR**
After that I had to rebuild/redo all the Language assignments for French on Pages, categories, menus, template.

The flag finally showed up...

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but, telling from the comments, a recurring problem. Seems like there can be multiple root causes. One thing to check is also that you have marked the default menu item for each language. If not, the corresponding language does not show in the language switcher.

Answer (score 1):

Found that You need to set a default homepage that can be in hidden menu (and redirect from later) to Language "All"

But then also go to each menu and make the page 1 language and also Homepage.

So for me I have now 3 language homepages menu items. All, En, De

How did I discover this:
I needed to turn on a module in the Admin:
Language Status Administrator Module
This makes a small button bottom left in the Admin, and modal points out 3 different topic per language installed, told me I had not any homepages, and so would get no flags. (Thanks to Per on Joomla forum answer from 2016)

Happy fixing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the languages in the Language Manager? under extensions..
and make sure you published the "System - Language Filter" plugin.

Comment: I already did all of those things you mentioned. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: did you define Content languages? it's an additional tab, in the Language manager screen..

Comment: Yes.. I find tutorial for this problem, and I allready did all of those things...

Answer (score 0):

```
Plugins ->  System - Language Filter  ->  Automatic Language Change -> No
```

This will prevent automatic language changin which is often reason for this

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and make your contributions there so that that niche community can grow.